# Removing all margins in an R graphics device

Tags: r

So I'm having a bit of trouble getting rid of the entire margin of a graphics device. I've set mar to 0, but there is still some persistent space around the edge. For example:

```
plot.new()
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot.window(c(0,1),c(0,1))
points(c(1,1,0,0),c(1,0,1,0))
```

[image]

I would like the points to be centered at the extreme edges of the plot. Is there a `par` that I am missing?

Comment: xlim and ylim are ignored by points(), their effect is already applied by the call to plot.window and cannot be changed subsequently.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is controlled by the arguments to ?par `xaxs` and `yaxs`. These are passed on by the ... argument of plot.window and other plot functions.

```
plot.window(c(0,1),c(0,1), xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")
```

From the help page for ?par, the default setting "r" extends the data range by 4 percent, and "i" uses the data range exactly:

> Style ‘"r"’ (regular) first extends the data range by 4
>   percent at each end and then finds an axis with pretty labels
>   that fits within the extended range.
>   Style ‘"i"’ (internal) just finds an axis with pretty labels
>   that fits within the original data range.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a side comment: to get rid of the spaces in a barplot, you need to use ylim instead of yaxs to get rid of the margin completely:

```
par(mar=c(0, 0, 0, 0)); barplot(1:10, xaxs="i", ylim=c(0,10), space=0)
```