# Define margins of PDF used for boxplot rendering

Tags: r, pdf, plot

When I render a boxplot on a PDF device in R there is a large white space besides the graph, especially at the top that i intent to reduce.

My script is basically just:

```
data <- read.csv("input.csv")
pdf(file="output.pdf", width=4, height=5)
boxplot(data, xlab="input graphs", ylab="vertex count")
```

This leads to something like:

[image: sample boxplot]

where the grey outline indicates the end of the document.

I tried to use the par attributes "mar" and "mai" as described in https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html but it had no effect.

```
boxplot(data, mar=c(0,0,0,0=, mai=c(0,0,0,0))
```

Do you have an advice how I can gain whitespace control? I want to have zero outer whitespace as the generated graph will be used in a Latex environment that provides sufficient spacings on its own. I am using Ubuntu as OS.

Comment: Please check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380235/removing-all-margins-in-an-r-graphics-device), if agree I will close as duplicate.

Comment: In case you didn't know, you can use `trim` of `graphicx` package in LATEX for cropping PDFs. In case you knew, I'll delete this.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the Latex package :) Indeed, the topic is close to the other one. Nevertheless I preferred the answer received here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `mar` right after `pdf`. Try this as an example

```
pdf(file = "test.pdf", width = 5, height = 5)
par(mar = c(5, 5, 0.05, 0.05))
set.seed(42)
plot(rnorm(20))
dev.off()
```